# Flow of Work Working With Node.JS HTTP server

Tags: node.js

Learning Node.JS at the moment.

Everything is going fine, just that i have a little challenge with the flow of work.

So i create an HTTP server that listens at a particular port. For example

```
var http = require("http");

http.createServer(function(request, response) {
  response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
  response.write("Hello World");
  response.end();
}).listen(8888);
```

It works fine. Only problem is that when i edit the file that has the above code, and try to start the node process again by typing node server.js i get the following error:

```
Error: EADDRINUSE, Address already in use.
```

So i learnt I need to kill the node process using ps before the changes can be reflected and before i can restart.

But this looks like a pain. Do i need to kill the node process anytime i make changes to the server i am writing?

I am sure there is a better way. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

During development I tend to just run node from the command line in a terminal window.  When I'm finished with the testing I just Ctrl-C to interrupt the current process which kills node and then press arrow-up enter to restart the process.

Comment: Ctrl-C does it...I initially was stopping the Node Server with Ctrl-Z. But I should think there would be a better way. Thanks! @beny23

Comment: CTRL-Z will suspend it in the background. Which can then be resumed with the fg command. So CTRL-Z will actually keep it in memory, with the file descriptors in use... which would be why your port could not be opened by a new process.

Answer (score 1):

my solution is as simple as

```
npm install dev -g
node-dev app.js
```

node-dev is the same as 'node' but automatically reruns app.js everytime any file in application dir (or subdir) is changed. it means restarting when static files are changed, too, but should be acceptable for development mode

Comment: "npm install dev -g" did not install for me on the Mac (fatal error: 'sys/inotify.h' file not found). So I used "npm install node-dev -g" which installs this module: https://github.com/fgnass/node-dev - worked like a charm on the Mac.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any easy way. Authors of node do not like hot-reloading idea, so this is the way it works.

You can hack it if you put your server in a module, `require` it from the main script, `fs.watchFile` the .js for changes and then manually stop it as a reaction to a file change, manually deleting it from the module cache (`require.cache` if I am not mistaken), and `require` it again.

Or run it in child process and kill and respawn it after a file change (that is, doing automatically what you now do by hand).

Comment: They do like hot core reloading, see nodemon, forever, supervisor, etc

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like [nodemon](https://github.com/remy/nodemon) ([video tutorial about it here](http://nodetuts.com/tutorials/14-some-nodejs-tools.html)) or [node-supervisor](https://github.com/isaacs/node-supervisor) so that the server auto-restarts when editing files.
If you want to manually do this, then just interrupt the process (CTRL+C) and re-run last command (node server.js).